# Programmatic creation of NSView in Cocoa

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa

i'm used to programming for iOS, and I've become very accustomed to the `UIViewController`. Now, i'm creating an OSX application and i'm having a few general questions on best practice.

In a `UIViewController` I generally setup my views in the `-(void)viewDidLoad` method - I don't actually create a custom `UIView` for the `UIViewController` unless it's really needed - so the `UIViewController` adds view to its own view, removes them, animates them and so forth - first off, is good practice?

And for my main question - what is the best practice in OSX? I like creating interfaces programatically and simply prefer it that way. If i, say create a new custom window and want to manage its view. What's the best way to do it, and where to i instantiate the user interface best?

Summary: How do i construct custom views programatically and set up a best-practice relationship between views and controllers in OSX? And is it considered good practice to use a view controller to create the views within its view?

Kind regards

Comment: OSX contains a lot of things that may be prone to error, like autolayout, minimize, maximise, resize. So try to create by xib and IB. However using code you can do, but for startups xib is an added sugar.

Comment: Hey, and thanks for the comment. Thing is, i'm not really new to objective-c, and managing autoresizingMask etc i prefer to do programatically. Are you saying that it's generally better to use xib and IB? Otherwise i'd still love to know what the best practice for doing everything programatically is :)

Comment: its ok, with IB, only few clicks and you are done. However for complex things even we need to program.

Comment: Still, my question isn't about just being able to create views. I want to know what the best practice is for the code-only approach, not necessarily the easiest way of creating UI.

Comment: I agree with @David - creating everything programmatically is much easier, faster, maintainable and less error prone than using IB. *Autolayout removes the need to size views at all* which was the hardest part of creating views programmatically in the past.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To construct the view in code in an NSViewController, override loadView and be sure to set the view variable. *Do not call super's implementation* as it will attempt to load a nib from the nibName and nibBundle properties of the NSViewController.

```
-(void)loadView
{
    self.view = [[NSView alloc] init];
    //Add buttons, fields, tables, whatnot
}
```

For a NSWindowController, the procedure is very similar. You should call windowDidLoad at the end of your implementation of loadWindow. Also the window controller does not call loadWindow if the window is nil, so you will need to invoke it during init. NSWindowController seems to assume you will create the window in code *before* creating the controller except when loading from a nib.

```
- (id)initWithDocument:(FFDocument *)document
                   url:(NSURL *)url
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        [self loadWindow];
    }

    return self;
}    
- (void)loadWindow
{
    self.window = [[NSWindow alloc] init];
    //Content view comes from a view controller
    MyViewController * viewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
    [self.window setContentView:viewController.view];
    //Your viewController variable is about to go out of scope at this point. You may want to create a property in the WindowController to store it.
    [self windowDidLoad];
}
```

### Some optional fancification (10.9 and earlier)

Prior to 10.10, NSViewControllers were not in the first responder chain in OSX. The menu will automatically enable/disable menu items for you when an item is present in the responder chain. You may want to create your own subclass of NSView with an NSViewController property to allow it to add the controller to the responder chain.

```
-(void)setViewController:(NSViewController *)newController
{
    if (viewController)
    {
        NSResponder *controllerNextResponder = [viewController nextResponder];
        [super setNextResponder:controllerNextResponder];
        [viewController setNextResponder:nil];
    }

    viewController = newController;

    if (newController)
    {
        NSResponder *ownNextResponder = [self nextResponder];
        [super setNextResponder: viewController];
        [viewController setNextResponder:ownNextResponder];
    }
}

- (void)setNextResponder:(NSResponder *)newNextResponder
{
    if (viewController)
    {
        [viewController setNextResponder:newNextResponder];
        return;
    }

    [super setNextResponder:newNextResponder];
}
```

Finally, I use a custom NSViewController that overrides setView to set the viewController property when I use my custom views.

```
-(void)setView:(NSView *)view
{
    [super setView:view];
    SEL setViewController = @selector(setViewController:);
    if ([view respondsToSelector:setViewController])
    {
        [view performSelector:setViewController withObject:self];
    }
}

- (BOOL)acceptsFirstResponder
{
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for a very good answer. Now, in `-(void)loadView`, is that where i should construct the subviews of the VC's view? Or should i do it in a custom views `-(id)initWithFrame:`? If in the `NSViewController`, how do i deal with the fact that i cannot possibly know the frame of the view i want to create?

Comment: I never specify frame sizes. Autolayout does it all for me. The window controller will automatically resize the contentView. If you use the viewController view in a subView, you will need to do add a resize mask or autolayout constraint. Edited answer.

Comment: Yes, loadView is where you add the subviews. I would recommend against doing the subview population in `init`. This gives you a chance to set properties that may be used (like a managed object context if you use core data) for view population between creating the controller and accessing the view.

Comment: Thanks! But what if you're creating a custom VC with multiple subviews which are in a layout based the views bounds?

Comment: If you are placing the VC's view into a container view (like NSSplitView, NSScrollView, NSTabViewItem, etc), the container view will automatically set the VC's view bounds. If the view you want to put the VC's view in is just a subview of something, you just take the existing view's bounds, remove the existing view, get your VC view, set the VC view bounds to the old views bounds, and add the VC view as the subview.

Answer (score 0):

> And for my main question - what is the best practice in OSX? I like
>   creating interfaces programatically and simply prefer it that way. If
>   i, say create a new custom window and want to manage its view. What's
>   the best way to do it, and where to i instantiate the user interface
>   best?

All these are done in  `awakeFromNib` and `init`.

The following code is creating many windows and storing them in array. For each window you can add views. And each view may contains all the controls you wish to have.

```
self.myWindow= [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:NSMakeRect(100,100,300,300)
                                                   styleMask:NSTitledWindowMask
                                                     backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered
                                                       defer:NO];


[self.myWindowArray addObject:self.myWindow];

for (NSWindow *win in self.myWindowArray) {
    [win makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
}
```

Comment: Thanks. All this i'm down with, so far :) However, what i'm interested in knowing is where do i construct the actual views managed by either the NSWindowController or the NSViewController. Say i have a view with a couple of text fields - where do i instantiate them and put them in the view hierarchy? Inside the class of the view managed by the controller or in the init/awakeFromNib or in e.g. loadView?

Comment: It depends as `awakeFromNib is called when the controller itself is unarchived from a nib. viewDidLoad is called when the view is created/unarchived. This distinction is especially important when the controller's view is stored in a separate nib file.`

Comment: So, if i decide not to use a nib file? Please note, that i want to avoid nib files as i'm doing a lot of view drawing, and custom UI components for one. Also, 'NSViewController' does not have the 'viewDidLoad' selector in Cocoa.

Comment: @David: Please check this code, if it helps you. http://www.keepandshare.com/doc/5604837/detailsview-zip-85k?da=y